# Receive Notification for SMS using iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms

I have been searching for this on Google for a while and maybe I'm not wording it right because I'm not an expert iPhone developer, but what I'm wondering is if there is some kind of notification or system event that my iPhone application I'm developing can "hook into" that will get raised whenever a text message arrives on my phone. I don't need to be able to read the message. I just need to know when a text message has arrive on my phone. If possible, I'd like to be able to get the phone number of the person sending the message. Is this possible in Objective-C/Cocoa?

Comment: Wow that really suprises me. I know it can be done in Android because I wrote my application in Android first (since I know Android development well) and I just always assumed that iPhones could do at least the same thing as an Android device could.

Comment: Yep... That's very sad... BTW, you can also use Java to develop Android apps, and you can't on iOS... Different platforms, different rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this with the public iOS APIs.

Comment: Heck, you can't even do this with Push.

Comment: Now correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that iOS 5 will have something called iMessage which WILL allow me to do this, but only using iPhone 5's and iOS 5, right?

Comment: iOS 5 is still in beta and under NDA; if you'd like to discuss it you should use http://devforums.apple.com.

Comment: Is there any notification in iOS6, when a text message arrives on iphone ?

Comment: "No, you can't do this with the public iOS APIs." :)