# SMS notifications in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, sony-smartwatch, imessage

I found `SMS notifications` are not supported in `iPhone`,but I found a video on `Pebble Smart watch` which sends `SMS` `notification` and `iMessage` `notification`. Here are the video and the application links.

http://www.razorianfly.com/2012/12/07/pebble-officially-announces-sms-and-imessage-support-for-iphone-video/

http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/iphone-news/pebble-watch-now-supports-iphone-sms-and-imessage-video/

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pebble-smartwatch/id592012721?mt=8

I also found on the web `SMS notifications` are supported only in `iOS6` but not `iOS5`

Previous stackoverflow and other links on SMS notifications.

[Registering SMS notification on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419982/registering-sms-notification-on-iphone)

[How to send email,sms notification from iPhone to Bluetooth LE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197503/how-to-send-email-sms-notification-from-iphone-to-bluetooth-le-device)

[Receive Notification for SMS using iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082256/receive-notification-for-sms-using-iphone?rq=1)

[sms notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683492/sms-notification?rq=1)

http://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2012/Nov/msg00088.html

What needs to be done to get notified? Implementing MAP Profile on the bluetooth device is suffcient ?

Comment: sooooo, is your question "does iOS 6 support applications to register for SMS notifications?"  or is it something else with SMS?

Comment: Michael: It's about how to register for SMS notifications in iOS6

Comment: I also want to implement SMS notification and iMessage notification in my app. If someone have the solution please post the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that iOS 6 adds message (SMS and iMessage) notification support in the form of the Bluetooth MAP (Message Access Profile).

So unless your intended usage involves you being connected via Bluetooth then you cannot use this feature of iOS6.

I do not think that it is possible to monitor the reception of incoming message with the Apple's Official iOS SDK since you would need to utilize a private framework, so you would need to make it a jail-broken app.

Comment: Alex: I would like to use Bluetooth using MAP.Can I use MAP with Core Bluetooth? Any examples how to use MAP with CoreBluetooth ?

Comment: @Ram I've tried to research this in the past, but have been unable to find an answer. Try posting it as another question.