# How to use Message Access Profile (MAP) in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

I would like to use Bluetooth using `Message Access Profile MAP` on `iPhone` for `SMS notifications`. Please find the related question link below.

How to get the SMS notifications in iPhone?

[SMS notifications in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494849/sms-notifications-in-ios6)

**EDIT**

OBEX  and OPP are not supported in iPhone. How Can I use `Message Access Profile (MAP)` in conjunction with `Serial Port Profile (SPP)`?Is it sufficient if MAP is implemented on blue tooth device or do I need to implement something else.Is there any API or some info on this.

Answer (score 0):

MAP profile is based on Obex(Object exchange) which is available on classic bluetooth .If you can do OPP(object exchange/file transfer) or phonebook transfer using corebluetooth fw available, MAP can also be implemented,though my understanding is that corebluetooth is meant only for BT LE(Low energy)

Comment: SPP enables a port over RFCOMM and is a interface to interact with RFCOMM. Obex is still required to implement map ,if obex library is not present then map cannot be implemented or another way is to implement the Obex parser at app level itself.