# How to use SMS and iMessage notifications on bluetooth device (like smart watch ) using Message Access Profile in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

How can I get notifications on bluetooth device (like smart watch) when there is an SMS or iMessage using Message Access Profile.These things are already implemented in smart watches like pebble.I would like to know how can I achieve this using ios sdk.

I posted couple of question on SMS,iMessage notifications using MAP in iPhone.Here are the links to those questions

[How to use Message Access Profile (MAP) in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579283/how-to-use-message-access-profile-map-in-iphone)

Comment: +1, have you found any solution ? Looking for same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't do anything to get MAP support — it's tied in to the push notification system. Any notification will get sent over MAP to any paired Bluetooth devices that implement it. (I think if they have a MAP paired device, the user can set which apps send MAP in notification settings.)

There are apparently some bugs at the moment, according to the Pebble team — sometimes you have to toggle the notifications switch for each app off then on again before it starts pushing them.

Comment: Hi Amy, can you please share more details on this, I am looking for the same? Thanks

Comment: Looking forward to see an example. Can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreTelephony framework.But you must user some private api.And I have some demo code for this. https://github.com/edison0951/AppNotifyBySMSDemo. And the finally solution is MAP.

Comment: I'd like to see a MAP solution.

Comment: finally,the device must use ANCS.the document is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html