# triggering a method in delphi xe when a sms is received on iphone

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe6

Hi I am trying to write a sms manager application for iOS via Delphi xe.
Is there any way for triggering a method in Delphi xe6 when a sms is received on iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS notifications in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494849/sms-notifications-in-ios6)

Comment: It's perfectly clear what this question is asking!

Comment: I agree with David here. It was immediately clear what the OP wants to achieve. Although the answer may be not satisfying.